# NUnit Inconclusive Confusion

Tags: visual-studio-2012, nunit, resharper

I have the following:-

```
[TestFixture]
class TaskServiceTest
{
    public void Implements_ITaskService()
    {
        var service = CreateService();

        Assert.That(service, Is.InstanceOf<ITaskService>());
    }

    private static ITaskService CreateService()
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

When I run that in Visual Studio / Resharper It is reported as 'Inconclusive'. The explanation of which in the [NUnit Docs](http://www.nunit.org/index.php?p=utilityAsserts&r=2.5.10) is

> The Assert.Inconclusive method indicates that the test could not be completed with the data available. It should be used in situations where another run with different data might run to completion, with either a success or failure outcome.

I don't see that holding here, so can anyone explain what I am doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: Please note: You are not using the `Assert.Inconclusive()` method, but your test result is inconclusive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just realised that it is because I missed the `[Test]` attribute off of the unit test.

```
[Test]
public void Implements_ITaskService()
{
    var service = CreateService();

    Assert.That(service, Is.InstanceOf<ITaskService>());
}
```

Comment: I don't understand the down vote. So I am voting up. But you could have deleted the question, I think.

Comment: I thought about deleting the question, but thought it might help someone else.